Determine if daylight savings is in use when converting time in BigQuery
I am trying to convert the timestamp associated with GA4 event data in BigQuery from UTC to my timezone.
I can easily do this with the following expression:
FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp), "UTC+10")

This works fine for days when we are on standard time (AEST). However, it gets it wrong when we are on daylight savings (AEDT). This would be a minor issue - but for some events the time conversion ends up on a different day then the actual day (i.e., event actually occurred at 12:50 am 24th Jan, but the conversion results in 11:50 pm 23rd Jan.
I know that when AEDT is in play, I need to use +11 and when AEST is in play, I need to use +10 - but how to tell BigQuery that?
Is there a way in BigQuery to tell if daylight savings adjustments should be applied to a timezone automatically? (i.e., I don't want to manually update the query and I could be looking at several years of data)

The answer is not to hard-code the conversion as UTC+10, but to specify the location. BigQuery will then determine if daylight savings should be applied
wrong:
FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp), "UTC+10")

right:
FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp), "Australia/Melbourne")

